# Insert query for electron using knex and sqllite not updating the table

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron, knex.js

I'm making an electron app and trying to implement a database connection using knex with sqlite3. I'm unable to make changes to my table and require help with doing so. I would like to add that I'm receiving my data correctly without any issues from a different page(it `colsole.log`'s it correctly), and I'm certain the issue lies with the database implementation. I'm providing the relevant code below of my setup and implementation

---

### Relevant Code

---

**Setup**

```
var knex = require("knex")({
  client: "sqlite3",
  connection: {
    filename: "./data.sqlite"
  }
});
```

**Implementation**

```
ipcMain.on("item:task", function (e, item) {
  console.log(item);    //correct item
  addTask.close();
  knex('task').insert({task: item}, {points: '3'}, {time: "this week"}).then(()=>{})
  knex('task').insert({task: item}, {points: '3'}, {time: "this week"}).catch(()=>{})
});
```